# Stationary Observers Question

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensors, general-relativity

An observer in a fixed location relative to our coordinate system has a worldline with constant $r, \theta, \phi$, and thereofre has four velocity $U$ with only the first component non zero. Because $U^aU_a=1$ and $U^0 >0$, the four velocity components are

$$U^0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2m/r}}, \text{      } U^a=0 \text{ for a=1,2,3}$$

How has this been derived mathematically?

.... As in special relativity, the acceleration felt by the observer is $\sqrt{-\alpha_a\alpha^a}$

Where has the negative sign come from and why is it needed?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for the physics stack exchange page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation
\begin{equation}
U^0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2m/r}}, U^a=0 \text{ for a=1,2,3}
\end{equation}
is obtained by solving the geodesic equation for the Schwarzschild metric
\begin{equation}
- d \tau^2=-(1-\frac{2m}{r}) dt^2+(1-\frac{2m}{r})^{-1} dr^2+r^2 d \theta ^2+ r^2 \sin^2(\theta) d \phi^2
\end{equation}
The Schwarzschild metric is a smooth spherically symmetric metric interpreted as the spacetime modelling the exterior of a spherically symmetric body of relativistic mass m. As a matter of fact, the angular dependence of the Schwarzschild metric is precisely the same as that of a sphere. It is therefore almost always sufficient to consider the equatorial plane $θ = π/2$, so that $dθ = 0$. In this coordinate system the metric is invariant under time translations,  and this allows us to define a  class of stationary observers whose world lines are given by constant values $r$, $\phi$ and $\theta$. Consequently, the lapse of proper time τ between two events at a fixed spatial point in Schwarzschild space-time is 
\begin{equation}
ds^2 =-(1-\frac{2m}{r}) dt^2= -g _{00}dt^2=-d \tau ^2
\end{equation}
The element of proper time $d \tau$ is measured by a clock at the particular point, while the element of world time dt is fixed for the whole manifold. The 4-velocity of a stationary observer is $U = (U^0,0,0,0)$ with $U^0= dt/d\tau$. The acceleration of the observer is
\begin{equation}
\alpha^a= U^b \nabla_b U^a= U^b \left(\frac{\partial U^a}{\partial x^b}+ \Gamma_{bc}^{a} U^c \right)= U^0 \left(\frac{\partial U^a}{\partial x^0}+ \Gamma_{00}^{a} U^0 \right)=(U^0)^2 \Gamma_{00}^{a}
\end{equation}
Thus
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\alpha}=(0,m/r²,0,0)
\end{equation}
The magnitude of the acceleration can be computed by using the dot product 
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\alpha} \cdot \boldsymbol{\alpha} = g_{ab} \alpha^a \alpha^b
\end{equation}
and then computing the square root. By doing that we have
\begin{equation}
|\boldsymbol{\alpha}|  =\left(1-\frac{2m}{r} \right)^{-1/2} \frac{m}{r^2}
\end{equation}
Since $g_{11}= -(1-\frac{2m}{r})^{-1}$ when defining $\sqrt{g_{ab} \alpha^a \alpha^b}= 
\sqrt{-g_{11} \alpha^1 \alpha^1}$ 
we have to use the sign minus to be consistent with definition of  $g_{11}$.

For large values of $r$ this is essentially Newtonian, but as $r → 2m$, the acceleration becomes infinite.